# Laravel 5.2 create migration error

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm trying to create a new migration from command line

```
php artisan make:migration create_table_tags --create=tags
```

Suddenly I got this error

> [ErrorException]
>     include(/home/loc/projects/shop/database/migrations/2016_08_16_094427_create_table_tags.php): failed to open stream: No such fi
>     le or directory

I created 2 migrations before without error.
Any idea?

**Update - Solution**
I fix this error with following steps

1. Create a file following the error

   ```
   touch /home/loc/projects/shop/database/migrations/2016_08_16_094427_create_table_tags.php
   ```
2. run command create migration again

   ```
   php artisan make:migration create_table_tags --create=tags
   ```

Still have no idea???

Comment: You say that "you have a solution" then say that "have no idea" and then post it as a question.  That is completely inconsistent.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to deleted a migration file before you did the rollback. So now Laravel is not sure how to rollback your database.

Easiest solution if you want to manually clear all the tables from your database, including the migration table.

Then just run `php artisan migrate` and it will install the table and run your migrations.

I think I will help you.